# Finding a relation between the same function depending of different variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In sample for exams there is a set of problem that go like this :

$ f(rcos(\theta),rsin(\theta)) = f_2 (r,\theta)$ and $x = rcos(\theta),y = rsin(\theta) $

Then they ask me to find a relation between $(\partial f / \partial x)^2 + (\partial f / \partial y)^2$ and some derivatives of $f_2$

At first I thought of using that :
$ (\partial f_2 / \partial r)*(\partial r / \partial x) + (\partial f_2 / \partial \theta)*(\partial \theta / \partial x) = \partial f / \partial x $ but seems like it doesn't take me anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot \cos \theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \sin\theta$$
$$\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot (-r\sin \theta )+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot r\cos\theta$$
Hence

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r}\cdot r\cos \theta +\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}\sin \theta \right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{1}{r}\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r}\cdot -r\sin \theta +\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}\cos \theta \right)$$

Hence

$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2 =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r}\cdot r\cos \theta +\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}\sin \theta \right)^2 + \frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r}\cdot -r\sin \theta +\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta}\cos \theta \right)^2 =$$

$$=\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial r}\right)^2 +\frac{1}{r^2}\left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial \theta} \right)^2$$

Comment: Damn that's exactly it thanks you so much, I really didn't think to use the formula the other way around !